# Display cost of product description to work on every line

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am a beginner and I am trying to get the cost from MYSQL database to work on every row.  I have created two columns of cost to show what I have attempted.  So far, I can get the cost, but I can only get it to work on last row using `class = "<?php echo $line_item; ?>"`  I also tried using `"class = results"` which displays the right cost but it displays on every row.  I know this looks like a mess but any help is much appreciated

```
<?php
include '****';
$order_num = $_REQUEST['order_n'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from items where order_n=$order_num"); ?>

<script src="javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table id='datatables' class='display' cellspacing='1'  table width = '1200'  border = '5'' div >

 <thead>
 <tr>                 
      <th><div align='left'><span class='style7'>Line</span></div></th> 
      <th><div align='left'><span class='style7'>Order #</span></div></th>
      <th><div align='left'><span class='style7'>Choose Product</span></div></th>           
      <th><div align='left'><span class='style7'>cost</span></div></th>
      <th><div align='left'><span class='style7'>cost</span></div></th>      
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <?php
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $line_item=$row['line_item']; ?>  
    <td><span class="text"><?=$row['line_item']?></td>  
    <td><span class="text"><?=$row['order_n']?></td>
    <td>
        <form action="">
            <select name="Description"  id="<?php echo $line_item; ?>" c
     class = "descrip_1"
                <option value="">Select a Item:</option>
                <option value="2x8-08 SYP #2">2x8-08 SYP #2</option>
                <option value="3/4 Galvanized Nut">3/4 Galvanized Nut</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td width=60px><label class="results"></label></td>
    <td width=60px><label class="<?php echo $line_item; ?>"></label></td>    
</tr><?php
            } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function() {
  function_1();
   $('.descrip_1').on('change', function() {
    function_2(this);
    });
 });

 function function_2(elem) {
 var $container = $(elem).parent().parent();
 var descrip_2= $container.find('.descrip_1').val();

   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: ({p : descrip_2}),  
            url: 'cost.php',
            success: function(data) {
            // Using "results will get cost on every row,
            // but the cost is the same on each row.
            // Should be different depending on line number
            $('.results').html(data);
            //Using php echo $line_item will work only one line.
            $('.<?php echo $line_item; ?>').html(data);             }
       });
  }

 function function_1(){
    }

  </script>
```

**PHP cost.php file to get cost**

```
 <?php
 include("*****");

 $name=$_POST['p'];

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM types WHERE Description = '".$name."'");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo "<table border='0' cellspacing='0'>
<th><font color='black'>".$row['Cost']."</th>
</table>"; ?>
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc ... tried mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: Yes it seems to do the same thing

Comment: Check your HTML it seems you're not closing some tags

Comment: `Using php echo $line_item will work only one line` yes because is outside a loop so only the last value should been showed

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Any idea how to get it work in a loop? So when I hit the dropdown the cost will populate in the correct row.  I want it to work in all rows, but only the row where I hit the dropdown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a variable class name.

Just use `<td width=60px><label class="line_item"></label></td>` and then

```
$container.find(".line_item").html(data);
```

in your jquery success.

Let me know if this not what you want, your question is a little confusing (do you want all rows to update or just the changed row? This should only change the changed row).

#### Edit

Okay, use `$(elem).closest("tr").find(".line_item").html(data);`

This is a solution that is loosely coupled with the corresponding html. I wrongly assumed the $container variable was, well, a container.

Comment: I want the script to work on all rows but I don't want the same cost on all rows.  Each product description will have a different cost.  The problem I am having in the above example works only on one row or it gives me the same cost on all rows.  I just wanted  to show the different ways I tried.  Ultimately in the end we will only have one column for cost once I figure out the correct way.

Comment: If I understand, you want it to update the row where you hit the drop down, which is what this does (and it works for every row). Just try this and tell me if it works for you!

Comment: container.find(".line_item").html(data); " Where exactly do I change or edit this?  ...didn't work when I tried it, but I probably did it wrong...thanks

Comment: Just replace the line `$('.<?php echo $line_item; ?>').html(data);` that you had previously. And container should have a `$` before it.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and it is not populating anything now in that cost column

Comment: ok im sorry..its works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!....Thanks for your help...very much appreciated!!!!!!!..I would vote but it wont let me..

Comment: @user2498276 Awesome! You can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking the arrow on the top-left of my answer. Best of luck :D

Answer (score 0):

Josh DM answered my question and it works now.  Here is what I did

html

```
    <td width=60px><label class="line_item"></label></td>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
   function_1();


    $('.descrip_1').on('change', function() {

       function_2(this);

       });  
      });

      function function_2(elem) {

// This will give the tr of the Element Which was changed



     var $container = $(elem).parent().parent();


   var descrip_2= $container.find('.descrip_1').val();


 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: ({p : descrip_2}),    
            url: 'listercust.php',
            success: function(data) {



 $(elem).closest("tr").find(".line_item").html(data);


 }


    });

     }

   function function_1(){     

   }

  </script>
```